# JSON-RPC Giving 400 Error and NaN value error showing in -- JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>

Tags: c#, json, websocket, json.net, json-rpc

In JSON-RPC If you run the source code below, it will display an error or NaN result, it will not return a JSON Object string as the response.

I have manually created a class and set `id` and `command` then serialized it but I'm unsure why an error occurred I have a lot of changes but not getting a good result.

I'm unsure what I have forgotten and am struggling to get this to work as expected.

My Expected result is: `{ "id": 1, "status": "success", "type": "response", "result": {} }`

```
namespace JsonRpcRipple
{
public class RipTest
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string command { get; set; }
}
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public JObject InvokeMethod()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://s1.ripple.com:51234/");

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        RipTest joe = new RipTest();
        joe.id = 1;
        joe.command = "ping";
        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe);

        // serialize json for the requestf
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        try
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            //inner exception is socket
            //{"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 23.23.246.5:8332"}
            throw we;
        }

        WebResponse webResponse = null;
            try
            {
                using (webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream str = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str))
                        {
                            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException webex)
            {

                using (Stream str = webex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str))
                    {
                        var tempRet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                        return tempRet;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         var ret = InvokeMethod();
        Response.Write(ret);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it should return {
  "id": 1,
  "status": "success",
  "type": "response",
  "result": {}
}

Comment: I have reformatted your question, removed begging for help (please don't do that we know you need help you have asked for help by starting a question), removed quote block when you're not quoting a source, added your expected result into question, so you can delete that comment. P.S Welcome to stack overflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Martin: good edits. If you see urgent begging, you are at liberty to remove that as well.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok sir its fine i will remember about it in future..!!!